# Change text color if checkbox is disabled

Tags: php, html, checkbox

How can I change the label color for this checkbox if the checkbox is disabled change the text color to red and if it's not change to green.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ($timelists[]='09:00:00'){
?>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info text-danger">
<input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]"value="09:00:00" <?php echo (in_array("09:00:00", $timelists)?"disabled='disabled'":"") ?>>
<label for="checkbox-15">
09:00 AM - 10:00 AM (ALREADY SCHEDULED)
</label>
</div>
<?php
}
else{
?>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info text-success">
<input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]"value="09:00:00" <?php echo (in_array("09:00:00", $timelists)?"disabled='disabled'":"") ?>>
<label for="checkbox-15">
09:00 AM - 10:00 AM (AVAILABLE)
</label>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

In This case the checkbox is disabled and label color is red 'text-danger' I got the same ouput when is not disabled and supposed to be the label color is green 'text-success'

Comment: `if ($timelists[]='09:00:00')` <- this doesn't look right (at all). What are you trying to test for?

Comment: @Jeto I have a array of values with that. If the value '09:00:00' is in the array I want to make the label color red which is already disabled.

Comment: @Elekpato This is invalid PHP however. You should use `in_array`.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm new in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As the label is immediately after the checkbox you can harness the simple rules available in standard CSS.
In this instance the `adjacent sibling selector` can be used by defining the style with `+`

So:

```
:disabled + label{ /* styles for label... */ }
```

as in

```css
label { color: green; } /* how the labels will look normally */

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label {
  color: red!important
} /* labels for checkboxes that are disabled */

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label:after{ content:"( ALREADY SCHEDULED )" }
```

```html
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info text-danger">
 <input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]" value="09:00:00" disabled />
 <label for="checkbox-15">09:00 AM - 10:00 AM</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info text-danger">
 <input id="checkbox-16" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]" value="10:00:00" />
 <label for="checkbox-16">10:00 AM - 11:00 AM</label>
</div>
```

```
label{color:green;}
label:after{content:"( AVAILABLE )"}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label{color:red!important}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label:after{content:"( ALREADY SCHEDULED )"}
```

Comment: OH. Thankyou! Save my day. One more thing how can I add some text into it for example if disabled add some text into label (ALREADY SCHEDULED)

Comment: again, use CSS to register the content using `:after` ~ see modified css above

Comment: `label:after { content: "AVAILABLE"; color: green; }
            input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label {
                color: red!important
        }` this show in all checkboxes even though it is disabled.

Comment: ? what do you mean?

Comment: I have multiple checkboxes. some are disabled. I want to add some text into the label depends if it is disabled or not. How to achieve that? I tried the :after.